# AES Encryption in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, encryption, aes

I'm trying to implement this utility class I found on [gutgames](http://www.gutgames.com) by James Craig, (you can view the class [here](http://www.gutgames.com/post/AES-Encryption-in-C.aspx)) with Windows Phone 7.

I had to replace all the references to System.Text.Encoding.ASCII to System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 since ASCII apparently is not supported in WP7. Besides that I'm still getting some errors because of references / namespaces not being found:

- PasswordDeriveBytes
- RijndaelManaged
- CipherMode

Firstly I don't have a clue what this is, secondly, are there any classes that I can use to replace these that indeed will be available in the Windows Phone 7 framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [PasswordDeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.aspx), [RijndaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) and [CipherMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx) types are not implemented in Silverlight. So you need to provide your own implementation of these types.

**BUT** I guess that use can use [AesManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class to do what you want. From MSDN page:

> The AES algorithm is essentially the Rijndael symmetric algorithm with
>   a fixed block size and iteration count. This class functions the same
>   way as the .NET Framework RijndaelManaged class but limits blocks to
>   128 bits and does not allow feedback modes.
>
> The cipher mode is always CBC, and the padding mode is always PKCS7.

Comment: In a similar position to you recently, I also found that I could use Rfc2989DeriveBytes instead of PasswordDeriveBytes in BOTH Windows Phone and a desktop app with satisfactory results. (The classes are not interchangeable mind)

Answer (score 1):

As @ie. already mentioned, these types are not included in Silverlight.

If you want to use them, you can download WP7 build of "bouncy castle library".

See this topic: [Using Bouncy Castle on Windows Phone 7](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-bouncy-castle-on-windows-phone-7.html)

The download links are at the bottom of this page. [Direct link](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=8503dda7ad75860b&resid=8503DDA7AD75860B!176&id=8503DDA7AD75860B!176) (BouncyCastle.Crypto.WP7 or BouncyCastle.Crypto.WP71)